# How can I grab a fresh state inside a useEffect hook body?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to build a debounce hook. I have seen several implementations before but none of them suit my needs: usually they delay executing a handler until the attempts to call the handler stop long enough.

```
useEffect(() => {
  timeout = setTimeout(handler, 500);

  return () => {
    if (timeout){
      clearTimeout(timeout);    
    }
  }
}, [handler]);
```

(or something like that.) I think this is flawed, because if the intent is to avoid spamming a long-running function, it doesn't take into account whether the function returns within the timeout or not. What if fetching search results takes longer than 500ms in this case?

Instead, I want to try and run a long running function (the handler.) If there isn't one running, execute the handler and return its promise. Also, use the finally block to check to see if the input has changed, and if so, fire the handler again.

My desired usage:

```
const [input, setInput] = useState<string>("");
const debouncedPromise = useDebounce(() => asyncFunction(input), [input]);
```

Anytime the input changes, the handler could be queued up if it isn't already running.

This is the code I've written:

```
import { DependencyList, useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";

interface IState<T> {
  handler?: () => Promise<T>;
  promise?: Promise<T>;
  isWaiting: boolean;
}

export const useDebounce = <T>(handler: () => Promise<T>, deps: DependencyList = []): Promise<T> | undefined => {
  const [state, setState] = useState<IState<T>>({
    handler,
    isWaiting: false
  });

  const stopWaiting = () => {
    console.log("stopWaiting");
    setState(previousState => ({ ...previousState, waiting: false }));
  };

  const run = () => {
    const promise = handler();
    promise.finally(stopWaiting);

    setState({
      handler,
      isWaiting: true,
      promise,
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("\nuseEffect");
    console.log(`deps: ${deps}`)
    console.log(`state.isWaiting: ${state.isWaiting}`);
    console.log(`state.handler: ${state.handler}`);
    console.log(`state.promise: ${state.promise}`);

    if (state.isWaiting){
      console.log(">>> state.isWaiting")
      return;
    }
    
    if (handler === state.handler){
      console.log(">>> handler === state.handler")
      return;
    } 
    
    if (state.isWaiting && state.promise && state.handler !== handler){
      console.log(">>> state.isWaiting && state.promise && state.handler !== handler")
      state.promise.finally(run);
      return;
    }

    if (handler !== state.handler){
      console.log(">>> handler !== state.handler")
      run();
    }

    console.log("end useEffect");
  }, [...deps, state.isWaiting]);

  return state.promise;
};
```

It works for the first invocation, but it never seems to free up the state.isWaiting to allow subsequence, pending handlers to be fired:

```
useEffect UseDebounce.ts:32
deps: T UseDebounce.ts:33
state.isWaiting: false UseDebounce.ts:34
state.handler: function () {
    return asyncFunction(input);
  } UseDebounce.ts:35
state.promise: undefined UseDebounce.ts:36
>>> handler !== state.handler UseDebounce.ts:55
asyncFunction called with T UseDebounce.tsx:9
end useEffect UseDebounce.ts:59

useEffect UseDebounce.ts:32
deps: T UseDebounce.ts:33
state.isWaiting: true UseDebounce.ts:34
state.handler: function () {
    return asyncFunction(input);
  } UseDebounce.ts:35
state.promise: [object Promise] UseDebounce.ts:36
>>> state.isWaiting UseDebounce.ts:39
asyncFunction resolved with T UseDebounce.tsx:12
stopWaiting UseDebounce.ts:16

useEffect UseDebounce.ts:32
deps: Ti UseDebounce.ts:33
state.isWaiting: true UseDebounce.ts:34 // This should be false at this point
```

I think I'm stuck with a stale state. How can I resolve this? Is there a better hook I can use to get my desired results? And how can I stop firing the handler once the input "settles down"?

Comment: Changing state doesn't abort the function you're in and it's not going to update the state variable.  It triggers a rerender and when the component function is called again in that rerender the state will be updated

Comment: "What if fetching search results takes longer than 500ms in this case?" The "500ms" delay is the delay before executing the function. That is to say, it will not be called until it the debounce hasn't been triggered for 500ms. How long the function takes to run is of no consequence.

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, you're not looking for a debounce, you're looking for a concurrency lock that will ensure that only one promise is being waited for at a time. Is that right?

Comment: @SlavaKnyazev I guess "concurrency lock" is a good way of describing it. You're right, the 500ms is an arbitrary waiting time. If I use a REST call with the contents of a text box for searching, I want the search to run immediately, or wait until a pending search completes before trying again, with whatever is in the text box when it does.

Comment: I guess you want to skip intermediate executions if there's a new input already, i.e. not just queue them?

Comment: Yeah. Once the searching is finished, it should call the handler again if the input has changed. Is this not a common task? I thought it would be a pretty common pattern.

Answer (score 0):

> It never seems to free up the `state.isWaiting`. I think I'm stuck with a stale state.

I think your problem is rather too fresh state. In particular, you are calling the hook with a new, different `handler` every time, so the only time that `handler === state.handler` could be true is that initial that initialises the state with the same handler. You might need to use `useCallback` on the function you're passing.

But even then your code has a problem. If the input changes multiple times while the function still running, you will call `state.promise.finally(run);` multiple times, which schedules `run` (with, indeed, some stale `handler`s) multiples times on the same promise, causing them to execute at the same time.

> Is there a better hook I can use to get my desired results?

I would not (only) use a state but rather a simple shared mutable ref for the input that's waiting to be used in the next function invocation. Also let the `run` function continue with the latest input by itself, instead of scheduling a fixed handler that's hard to cancel.

So I'd write

```
interface ResultState<T> {
  running: boolean;
  result?: PromiseSettledResult<T>;
}
function useAsyncEvaluation<T, Args extends DependencyList>(fn: (...args: Args) => Promise<T>, input: Args): ResultState<T> {
  const args = useRef<Args | undefined>();
  const [state, setState] = useState<ResultState<T>>({running: false});
  
  function run() {
    const next = args.current;
    if (!next) return false;
    args.current = undefined;
    fn(...next).then(
      value => ({status: "fulfilled", value}),
      reason => ({status: "rejected", reason})
    ).then(result => {
      setState({running: run(), result});
    );
    return true;
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    args.current = input;
    setState(old => {
      if (old.running) {
        return old;
      } else {
        // calling run() inside the state update prevents race conditions
        return {running: run(), result: old.result};
      }
    });
    return () => {
      args.current = undefined;
    };
  }, input)
  return state;
}
```

Notice that this has [the slightly undesirable behaviour of updating state in an effect](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/you-might-not-need-an-effect) during the first render and in response to an `input` change. You might not actually want to do this anyway - rather, return the function from the hook and call it from your event handlers.